# How I do get the data from the <font> tag from a given tr tag

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Here is the HTML code for tr tag:

```
<tr id="tr_m_1570:240HJY" class="flavored_option_display_enabled">
    <td width="1" height="1" valign="Top"><img src="https://si.cdn.abc.com/images/global/configurator/general/spacer.gif" border="0" height="1" width="1"></td>
    <td width="100%">
        <table name="t_m_1570:240HJY" id="t_m_1570:240HJY" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="9" height="1" valign="Top"><img src="https://si.cdn.abc.com/images/global/configurator/general/spacer.gif" border="0" height="1" width="9"></td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <a name="m_1570:240HJY" id="m_1570:240HJY"></a>
                        <input type="checkbox" onmousedown="validateMouseDown(event);" onkeydown="validateKeyDown(event);" onclick="tealeafAddEvent(this, 'custom_checkbox_click','m_1570_240HJY'); checkOnClick(event), enableQtyText('m_1570','240HJY','true');" id="m_1570" name="m_1570" displayname="m_1570_240HJY" value="240HJY">
                    </td>
                    <td width="100%" style="line-break:strict;word-break:keep-all;line-height:2">
                        <div>
                            <span id="sq_m_1570_240HJY" style="display:inline" ;=""><input type="text" id="q_m_1570:240HJY" name="q_m_1570:240HJY" size="1" class="qty_text_box_set" onkeyup="showQtyUpdateButton('sqb_m_1570_240HJY')" value="1" onfocus="javascript:enableQtyText('m_1570','240HJY','false');"></span>
                            <span id="sqb_m_1570_240HJY" style="display:none" ;=""><input type="button" id="qb_m_1570_240HJY" name="qb_m_1570_240HJY" size="2" style="font-size:10px" value="Update" onclick="updateOptionQty('q_m_1570:240HJY','m_1570','240HJY')"></span>
                            <font size="1">&nbsp;240GB Solid State Drive SATA Read Intensive 6Gbps 512 2.5in Hot-plug Boot 3.5 HYB CARR&nbsp;<span id="op_m_1570:240HJY" name="op_m_1570:240HJY">[£318.00&nbsp;or&nbsp;£12/month<sup>-1</sup>]</span></font>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--option1 close-->
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the data from the ***font*** tag.

Comment: Dont know how to do it in python, but are you tried to find font tag via xpath and read it's "size" attribute?

Comment: I want to get the data present in font tag.

Comment: Jeff - Kindly go through my all posts. I am sharing my answers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple CSS selector

```
table[id='t_m_1570:240HJY'] font
```

Note that I didn't use the typical, `#t_m_1570:240HJY font` because CSS selector logic doesn't like the colon in there.

From there, you can return the text inside using the standard `.text` and do what you want with it.

Comment: I am able to locate the required element with the below code:

browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr[@id='tr_m_1570:240HJY']/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/font")


But not able to get the text from the "font" tag.

Comment: When I created a temp file with your HTML, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I can fetch the data for which I was looking for using the below code:

```
hd_PriceText=browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[@id='tr_m_1570:1025516']/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/font/span").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```